# Failed to load TPM device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, arm64

I have a board from a no name manufacturer with a tpm 2.0 device LetsTrust but I am getting an error while trying to load the TPM.
The board has Ubuntu arm64 installed, the kernel version is 4.9.170.

I have added the following modules to be loaded on boot:

tpm_tis_spi
tpm_tis_core
tpm

but I still can't see the tpm on /dev, when I check the boot logs with dmesg I only see **fly error: tpm_tis_remove ** I am not sure what it means exactly but it seems the kernel couldn't recognize the TPM for some reason.
There is a way where I could get more information to understand why this is happening? we have no manual from the manufacturer so I can't ask them for help.
I have tried to compile a new kernel with TPM support to already load those drivers as modules but the OS disk is somehow embedded in the board and I couldn't find any bootloader to be able to tell it to boot from the new kernel.

Comment: Is it present in the board's devicetree? Maybe it needs a devicetree overlay?

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott, thank you very much for this hint.
I am not familiar with this concept, I just read about it and it makes a lot of sense.
I will try this out, there is a simple way to implement this? I have no knowledge of C programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Use updated uboot code and check tpm2 code in cmd folder in uboot.